# How to Break Import Loop in python

Tags: python

I have a situation where there two related large  python classes and hence i have put them in separate files. Let say classes are Cobra and Rat.

Now need to call methods of Rat from methods of Cobra and vice versa.
For this i need to import Cobra in Rat.py and Rat in Cobra.py

This creates an import loop and gives an error. Cant import Cobra inside Cobra.

How to fix this??

**Cobra.py**:

```
import Rat
class Cobra():
    def check_prey(self, rat ):
        # Some logic 
        rat.foo()
```

**Rat.py**:

```
import Cobra
class Rat():
    def check_predator(self, snake ):
        # some_logic ..
        snake.foo()
```

Comment: None of the code you show exhibits that problem.

Comment: This shouldn't happen, two classes cannot know each other. If you are using `Rat` and `Cobra` classes, how about a common base class `Animal`? This way you can import `Animal` in both `Rat` and `Cobra`.

Comment: "two classes cannot know each other" is just plain wrong.  Bi-directionality of navigation is fundamental feature of OO and available in most OO languages, C++, Java, C#.

Comment: But why would a cobra need rat for anything?

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen ... to eat it? :)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you don't use `Cobra` in the class definition of `Rat` or vice versa (i.e. only used inside methods), then you can actually move the import statement to the bottom of the file, by which time the class definition would already exist.

```py
# Cobra.py
class Cobra:
    # ...
    def check_prey(self, rat):
        # some logic
        rat.foo()
    
import Rat
```

```py
# Rat.py
import Cobra
class Rat:
    # ...
    def check_predator(self, snake):
       # some_logic ..
       snake.foo()
```

Or you can limit the scope of the import:

```
# Cobra.py
class Cobra:
    # ...
    def check_prey(self, rat):
        import Rat
        # some logic
        rat.foo()
```

```py
# Rat.py
import Cobra
class Rat:
    # ...
    def check_predator(self, snake):
       # some_logic ..
       snake.foo()
```

If you don't use the `Rat` and `Cobra` class names directly, then you don't even need the import statements at all: as long as the properties and functions exist in the `rat` or `snake` instances, Python doesn't care what class they're from.

In general, there is no foolproof way to avoid `import` loops. The best you can do is refactor your code and do some of the things I mentioned above.