# python import dep_root not found

Tags: python, pip, python-3.6

I did `pip install` of `pyopenfdm` and tried to `import pyopenfdm`. It threw an error saying `module deps not found`. I did pip install deps and now it is throwing an error as follows

```
import pyopenfdm
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/<userName>/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyopenfdm/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from deps import dep_root
ImportError: cannot import name 'dep_root'
```

I tried googling and searching here but in vain. Appreciate if I can get some help please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case you have several imports, sometimes this points to having circular depended imports. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199466/how-to-break-import-loop-in-python) topic.

**EDIT:**
The problem seems to be related to the import command itself. `import deps import dep_root` is valid in python2, but not in python3.

If you modify `\Anaconda\envs\py3k\Lib\site-packages\pyopenfdm\__init.py`
by adding a dot in front of "deps"
`from .deps import dep_root` your import should work.

According to [pep-0404](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0404/):

> In Python 3, implicit relative imports within packages are no longer
>   available - only absolute imports and explicit relative imports are
>   supported. In addition, star imports (e.g. from x import *) are only
>   permitted in module level code.

Comment: I dont think the error I am seeing has anything to do with the other topic. If I do import pyopenfdm on the python console, I see the same issue as above

Comment: right, I wasn't sure whether you had several imports. I managed to reproduce your problem using python3. The problem does not exist in python2. I edited my answer to reflect how to fix this error.